# latex macros \def defining multiple command for equations, math mode disappear

Tags: macros, equations, overleaf

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{}
\def\bel#1\eel{\begin{align}\begin{split}#1\end{split}\end{align}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\bel
a^v=2
\eel
\end{document}
```

Then the error says: ^ must be inside math mode.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

I also tried

```
\def\bel{\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}}
\def\eeq{\end{aligned}\end{equation}}
```

But it doesn't fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Don't do that. You will end with a document basically unreadable for anybody (apart from you), and any good editor will be able to generate the environment with a simple key sequence.

Comment: Anyway, if you insist, the best approach is to use the package `environ` or the `\NewDocumentEnvironment` command (see `xparse`)

Comment: Next time write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: Okay, I wrote a minimal example containing your code snippet and it doesn't error. (the second one does error as expected.) So write a minimal working example.

Comment: Ummm, your MWE works fine for me.

Comment: Added a minimal working example. Seems that it works fine for some of you. I guess it's an issue with the overleaf editor?

Comment: Yes, this was mentioned in the chat yesterday that it got broken on Overleaf. It was also said that a fix is on the way. "one of our parsers got into an infinite loop over any `{\begin{foo}}` or `{\end{foo}}`, causing the editor to eat itself out of memory."

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions